# unnest() not exploding array, returns error Column alias list has 1 entries but 't' has 2 columns available

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have some json data which includes a property 'characters' and it looks like this:

```
select json_data['characters'] from latest_snapshot_events
```

Returns:    `[{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":60,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,"CHAR_TIER":1,"ITEM":10,"shards":0,"CHAR_TPIECES":0,"CHAR_A5_LVL":0,"CHAR_A2_LVL":1,"CHAR_A4_LVL":1,"ITEM_CATEGORY":"Character","ITEM_LEVEL":3},{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":50,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,"CHAR_TIER":1,"ITEM":39,"shards":0,"CHAR_TPIECES":0,"CHAR_A5_LVL":0,"CHAR_A2_LVL":1,"CHAR_A4_LVL":1,"ITEM_CATEGORY":"Character","ITEM_LEVEL":2},{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":80,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,"CHAR_TIER":1,"ITEM":6801450488388220,"shards":0,"CHAR_TPIECES":0,"CHAR_A5_LVL":1,"CHAR_A2_LVL":1,"CHAR_A4_LVL":1,"ITEM_CATEGORY":"Character","ITEM_LEVEL":4},{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":85,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,"CHAR_TIER":1,"ITEM":8355588830097610,"shards":0,"CHAR_TPIECES":5,"CHAR_A5_LVL":0,"CHAR_A2_LVL":1,"CHAR_A4_LVL":1,"ITEM_CATEGORY":"Character","ITEM_LEVEL":4}]`

This is returned on a single row. I would like a single row for each item within the array.

I found several SO posts and other blogs advising me to use `unnest()`. I've tried this several times and cannot get a result to return. For example, [here is the documentation from presto](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/migration/from-hive.html). The bottom covers unnest as a stand in for hive's lateral view explode:

```
SELECT student, score
FROM tests
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(scores) AS t (score);
```

So I tried to apply this to my table:

```
characters as (
select
  jdata.characters
from latest_snapshot_events
cross join unnest(json_data) as t(jdata)
)
select * from characters;
```

where `json_data` is the field in latest_snapshot_events that contains the the property 'characters' which is an array like the one shown above.

This returns an error:

> [Simba]AthenaJDBC An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 69:12: Column alias list has 1 entries but 't' has 2 columns available

How can I unnest/explode `latest_snapshot_events.json_data['characters']` onto multiple rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_parse` works if your initial data is a JSON string. However, for `array(row)` types (i.e. an array of objects/dictionaries), casting to `array(json)` will convert each row into an array, removing all keys from the object and preventing you from using dot notation or `json_extract` functions.

To unnest `array(row)` data, the syntax is much simpler:

```
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(my_array) AS my_row
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `characters` is a JSON array in textual representation, you'll have to:

1. Parse the JSON text with [`json_parse`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse) to produce a value of type [JSON](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/language/types.html#json).
2. Convert the JSON value into a SQL array using [`CAST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#cast-to-json).
3. Explode the array using [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest).

For instance:

```sql
WITH data(characters) AS (
    VALUES '[{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":60,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,"CHAR_TIER":1,"ITEM":10,"shards":0,"CHAR_TPIECES":0,"CHAR_A5_LVL":0,"CHAR_A2_LVL":1,"CHAR_A4_LVL":1,"ITEM_CATEGORY":"Character","ITEM_LEVEL":3},{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":50,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,"CHAR_TIER":1,"ITEM":39,"shards":0,"CHAR_TPIECES":0,"CHAR_A5_LVL":0,"CHAR_A2_LVL":1,"CHAR_A4_LVL":1,"ITEM_CATEGORY":"Character","ITEM_LEVEL":2},{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":80,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,"CHAR_TIER":1,"ITEM":6801450488388220,"shards":0,"CHAR_TPIECES":0,"CHAR_A5_LVL":1,"CHAR_A2_LVL":1,"CHAR_A4_LVL":1,"ITEM_CATEGORY":"Character","ITEM_LEVEL":4},{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":85,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,"CHAR_TIER":1,"ITEM":8355588830097610,"shards":0,"CHAR_TPIECES":5,"CHAR_A5_LVL":0,"CHAR_A2_LVL":1,"CHAR_A4_LVL":1,"ITEM_CATEGORY":"Character","ITEM_LEVEL":4}]'
)
SELECT entry
FROM data, UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(characters) AS array(json))) t(entry)
```

which produces:

```
                               entry
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":60,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,...
 {"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":50,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,...
 {"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":80,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,...
 {"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1,"ITEM_POWER":85,"CHAR_A3_LVL":1,...
```

In the example above, I convert the JSON value into an `array(json)`, but
you can further convert it to something more concrete if the values inside each 
array entry have a regular schema. For example, for your data, it is 
possible to cast it to an `array(map(varchar, json))` since every element in the
array is a JSON object.

Comment: In case anyone else lands here, I had to add `cross join` before `unnest()`. So `FROM data, cross join UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(characters) AS array(json))) t(entry)`

Comment: “ FROM data, cross join UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(characters) AS array(json))) t(entry); “

OR

“ FROM data, UNNEST(CAST(json_parse(characters) AS array(json))) t(entry); “

Both the syntax performs cross join. What do you want to achieve by adding cross join explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck with this error trying to unpivot data.

This might help someone:

```
SELECT a_col, b_col
FROM
(
SELECT MAP(
        ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        ARRAY[1, 2, 3, 4]
       ) my_col
) CROSS JOIN UNNEST(my_col) as t(a_col, b_col)
```

t() allows you define multiple columns as outputs.